# SSRS report URL - shows parameters but hide rest of header

Tags: reporting-services, query-string, querystringparameter, ssrs-2014

I'm trying to use querystring parameters to suppress parts of the header of an SSRS report (using SSRS 12.0.4213.0).

[image: SSRS Header Sections]

What I want to do is supress the breadcrumb and menu panel (marked in red above) at the very top and maybe also the toolbar below (marked in blue) while leaving the parameter bar (marked in green) intact.

What combination of querystring parameters can I use to achieve this? I've read the Microsoft documentation and have searched SO but have been unable to find a combination of parameters for the URL which achieve this.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this via URL params as these are to do with the report, not to do with controlling report server areas of the page.  Try looking at the report server config file, may well be a setting in there but I've not come across one.

Comment: Does this article help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference

Comment: @JerryRitcey yes, I already read that page and browsed the rest of the MS site relating to this, but couldn't find specifically what I'm looking for (a way to suppress the breadcrumb-containing bar without also suppressing the parameters bar), but if you can see it there, please point it out to me.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, it would be nice to know why so I can improve my question.

Comment: If you render the URL via a string like http://myserver/ReportServer/pageswhatever it should hide the breadcrumb trail by default.